# kafka streams protobuf cast exception

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I am using Kafka streams to read and process protobuf messages.

I am using the following properties for the stream:

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getGroupId());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getClientId());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getApplicationId());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getBootstrapServers());

        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.StringSerde.class);
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaProtobufSerde.class);
        properties.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getSchemaRegistryUrl());
        properties.put(KafkaProtobufDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_PROTOBUF_VALUE_TYPE, ProtobufData.class);
        return properties;
    }
```

but while running I encounter this error:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage cannot be cast to class model.schema.proto.input.ProtobufDataProto$ProtobufData (com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage and model.schema.proto.input.ProtobufDataProto$ProtobufData are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

My `.proto` files looks as follows:

```
import "inner_data.proto";
package myPackage;

option java_package = "model.schema.proto.input";
option java_outer_classname = "ProtobufDataProto";

message OuterData {
    string timestamp = 1;
    string x = 3;
    repeated InnerObject flows = 4;
}
```

(I have two separate proto files)

```
package myPackage;

option java_package = "model.schema.proto.input";
option java_outer_classname = "InnerDataProto";

message InnerData {
  string a = 1;
  string b = 2;
  string c = 3;
}
```

I would like to know why Kafka uses `DynamicMessage` even though I gave the specific protobuf value class in the properties and how to fix this?

Comment: Refer: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-protobuf.html#protobuf-deserializer
It says "Finally, if no type is provided or no type can be derived, the deserializer uses the schema to return an instance of a Protobuf DynamicMessage."

Comment: Is the inconsistency between your `.proto` file message called `OuterData` and the java class called `ProtobufData` a typo? Because if that is not a typo then this might be the cause of your error, using different classes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while trying to make Kafkastream working with protobuf,

I solved this issue by using specifically `KafkaProtobufSerde` to configure the streambuilder AND by specifiing explicitly the class to deserialize to with this line: `serdeConfig.put(SPECIFIC_PROTOBUF_VALUE_TYPE,ProtobufDataProto.class.getName());`

```
    /*
     *  Define SpecificSerde for Even in protobuff
     */
    final KafkaProtobufSerde< ProtobufDataProto > protoSerde = new KafkaProtobufSerde<>();
    Map<String, String> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
    serdeConfig.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, registryUrl);
    /*
     * Technically, the following line is only mandatory in order to de-serialize object into GeneratedMessageV3
     * and NOT into DynamicMessages : https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/DynamicMessage
     */
    serdeConfig.put(SPECIFIC_PROTOBUF_VALUE_TYPE,ProtobufDataProto.class.getName());
    protoSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
```

Then i can create my input stream and it will be deserialized:

```
 //Define a Serde for the key
 final Serde<byte[]> bytesSerde = Serdes.ByteArray();
 //Define the stream
 StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
 streamsBuilder.stream("inputTopic", Consumed.with(bytesSerde, protoSerde));
 /* 
 add your treatments, maps, filter etc
 ...
 */
 streamsBuilder.build();
```